# how to write on error rollback in IBM DB2 WinSQL sql script

Tags: transactions, db2, winsql

Example :

Let's say, I have 3 INSERT statements. I am using WinSQL to execute the following script:

```
SAVEPOINT A;

INSERT_STATEMENT 1;

INSERT_STATEMENT 2;

INSERT_STATEMENT 3;

Now, INSERT_STATEMENT 1 is successful.

INSERT_STATEMENT 2 is successful.

INSERT_STATEMENT 3 has got into error, so I want to rollback to SAVEPOINT A;
```

How can we do that?

Please note: We are allowed to run a SQL script in the production through mainframe, so not sure if writing a function(with condition codes) for this will work because functions work when a language like JAVA is involved. My point is to write script directly into winSQL without any external programming language.
Could you please guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the statements between a BEGIN and END

Comment: I tried using the following script :
BEGIN WORK;

LOCK TABLE TABLE_NAME

INSERT_STATEMENT;
UPDATE_STATEMENT;

COMMIT WORK;


But getting an error :

Error: SQL0199N  The use of the reserved word "WORK" following "" is not valid.  Expected tokens may include:  "DECLARE".  SQLSTATE=42601.


Not sure if BEGIN-END works in DB2.

Any idea about how we can write script.

Thank you